# Why is it giving me an error with the _T() function

Tags: c++

I have this code and its not working correctly, i arleady did `#include <tchar.h>`

```
char gmod[] = "client.dll";
DWORD gba = GetModuleBaseAddress(_T(gmod), procID);
```

in the part where its _T(gmod) there is a red line under it that says

> Expands to: Lgmod
> The identifier "Lgmod" is not defined

please help, im a beginner at C++ and i havent found solution to this

I tried searching and doing chatgpt fixes but got me even more errors

Comment: ChatGPT doesn't know how to program. It certainly doesn't know how to teach beginners to program. What is `_T`?

Comment: i dont know i was following a tutorial and i think its this: _T stands for “text”. It will turn your literal into a Unicode wide character literal if and only if you are compiling your sources with Unicode support.

Comment: It is a macro, not a function.  It can only work on string literals.  As long as you use char[], get ahead with GetModuleBaseAddressA(gmod, procID);  [Backgrounder](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_T()` is not a function, it is a **macro**, and it only works on string literals.

It is obsolete. I recommend using `wchar_t` for strings passed to Windows functions and structures. This can be done by replacing `char` with `wchar_t`, and using `L""` string literals instead of `""` string literals.

```c
wchar_t gmod[] = L"client.dll";
DWORD gba = GetModuleBaseAddress(gmod, procID);
```

This works as long as the `UNICODE` macro is defined, which should be defined for all new projects.

The `_T()` macro is there so you can build Unicode and non-Unicode versions of the same project, using the same source code. That’s not normally something you’d want to do these days.

(You can alternatively use the non-Unicode versions.)

```c
// This works, but it’s the old, non-Unicode version.
char gmod[] = "client.dll";
DWORD gba = GetModuleBaseAddressA(gmod, procID);
```